# Two Wiener process under same martingale measure Q

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-volatility, wienerprocess

Let $W_1,$ $W_2$ be to Wiener processes under the martingale measure $Q$. What can be said about $dW_1*dW_2$? I know that $$(dW_i)^2=dt$$ but what about the case with two different wiener processes?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the measure is the martingale measure. If two processes are both BMs in some probability space, then their covariation process is just $\rho t$ where $\rho$ is the correlation between them.

Answer (score 2):

The following is not a proof but some reasoning:

If you consider the L2-limits then you see something along the lines:
$$
dW^2 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n (W_{t_{j+1}} - W_{t_{j}})^2 \rightarrow t
$$
For $W_1, W_2$ with correlation $\rho$ this transaltes to
$$
dW^1 dW^2 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n (W_{t_{j+1}}^1 - W_{t_{j}}^1)(W_{t_{j+1}}^2 - W_{t_{j}}^2) \rightarrow \rho t, 
$$
which can be seen by considering that $\left((W_{t_{j+1}}^1 - W_{t_{j}}^1),(W_{t_{j+1}}^2 - W_{t_{j}}^2)\right)$ is bivariate Gaussian.

You find details in [Introduction to Stochastic Differential
Equations (SDEs) for Finance](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05309.pdf) on page 19 Correlated Brownian Motion.